# Splitting stacked data from one cell and delimiting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to split the stacked data in cell A1 and out put it in B1 so that is is delimited by pipes and the line breaks removed. Is this at all possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use substitute and char function. 10 is the code for new line.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"|")
```

Comment: I never thought this was possible. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

VBA Version just because you tagged it as VBA also:

```
Range("B1").Formula = Join(Split(Application.transpose(Range("A1").Text),vblf),"|")
```

Note: You said "commas" in your question but your sample showed a pipe hence why we both used a pipe

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did. Thanks for your response and thanks for pointing out my error. Have amended so anyone else seeing won't be confused.